# How to remove strings from a list which contain a sub-string?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that's structured as follows:

```
['3M', 'Saint Paul, Minnesota', 'A. O. Smith', 'Milwaukee, Wisconsin', 'Abbott Laboratories',...]
```

I want to remove the strings corresponding to cities, which all contain a comma `,`.

So far my code is:

```
for name in names:
    if '</a>' in name:
        names.remove(name)
    if re.search(', Inc.',name) != None:
        name = name.replace(',',"")
        names.append(name)
    if ',' in name:
        names.remove(name)
```

But I get an error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` at `names.remove(name)`.

I can't seem to understand why the 1st block, which drops if the string contains `</a>` works fine, but the one with commas does not.

Comment: If the first block removes `name`, then it isn't there to be removed by later blocks.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to change the size of a collection as you're iterating over it. In Python, you shouldn't try to "remove things I don't want", but rather "only retain things I do want", which means filtering a collection and creating a new collection made up of items you want to retain, and not modifying the original list in-place.

Comment: What does your program do if the name is `</a>,`?  What *should* it do?

Comment: @PaulM. so I should create a new list, and append to it if the criteria are not satisfied?

Comment: @ScottHunter that makes sense. And all I'm trying to do at this point is clean up the data. I'm trying to make a list of company names and match them to tickers. The data is read in from Wiki in HTML so just having to deal with some odd ball lines of HTML.

Comment: @StCheese Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off my comment about how, in Python, we generally want to "retain things we like" rather than "purge things we don't like". This is preferable because we can avoid changing the size of a list as we're iterating over it, which is never a good idea. We achieve this by filtering the original list based on a predicate (`is_desirable` in this case). A predicate is a function/callable that accepts a single parameter and returns a boolean. When used in conjunction with `filter`, we can create an iterator that yields only those items that satisfy the condition of the predicate. We then consume the contents of that iterator to build up a new list:

```
names = [
    '3M',
    'Saint Paul, Minnesota',
    'A. O. Smith',
    'Milwaukee, Wisconsin',
    'Abbott Laboratories'
]

def is_desirable(name):
    return "</a>" not in name and "," not in name

print(list(filter(is_desirable, names)))
```

Output:

```
['3M', 'A. O. Smith', 'Abbott Laboratories']
```

However, this does not take into account the other operation you're performing: If the current name contains the substring `", Inc."`, we still want to retain this name, but with the comma removed.

In this situation, I would define a generator that only yields the items we want to retain. If we come across the substring `", Inc."`, we modify the current name and yield it. The generator's contents are then consumed to build up a new list:

```
def filtered_names(names):
    for name in names:
        if ", Inc." in name:
            name = name.replace(",", "")
        if "</a>" in name or "," in name:
            continue
        yield name

print(list(filtered_names(names)))
```

This is by no means the only way of doing this. This is my personal preference.

Comment: This is perfect! I used `filter()` originally to filter out blanks and didn't realize that it only uses logicals so this solution is very succinct; just need to list out all `or` criteria (of which there are many). 
And the 2nd solution you offer is even better as I need to make several replacements. Currently I was doing
```for name in names:
    if '&amp;' in name:
        name = name.replace('&amp;',"&")
        names.append(name)
names = [name for name in names if "&amp;" not in name]
```
Again this is very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to filter out invalid elements (i.e. the ones containing comma).

```py
>>> l = ['3M', 'Saint Paul, Minnesota', 'A. O. Smith', 'Milwaukee, Wisconsin', 'Abbott Laboratories']
>>> result = [e for e in l if "," not in e]
>>> result
['3M', 'A. O. Smith', 'Abbott Laboratories']
```

Comment: What about the `</a>` and `, Inc.`? stuff?

Comment: The request was "I want to remove the strings corresponding to cities, which all contain a comma ,"

Comment: And the code addresses other stuff, which is what is causing the problem w/ dealing with the comma.

Comment: Thanks @crissal this partly works on its own (ex. the loop). However, I need to exclude several criteria, namely anything that contains `</a>` however using something like `l = [e for e in l if "," or "</a>" not in e]` does not remove either.